How to resample spline at predetermined x positions for non-monotonic curve
This outstanding example provides an option to create a spline for a non-monotonic curve : Cubic spline for non-monotonic data (not a 1d function)
However, I now need another step - to obtain y-values for given x-values. I cannot figure out how to extend the use of spline for this without loops. I guess I could look for a solution of some r that gives some x_i, but this would be a very long process.
Let's say I need the value of y at x = 4.5. But the closest is 'spline(0.1)' that gives  array([4.54115695, 0.40519822])

Are those values not the y values along the x = 4.5 line? The curve in the example you linked to is not a function so there isn't a unique mapping.

you're right @jared

Found this solution using first upsampling and then interpolating using radial basis functions (the only one that worked due to non-monotonic x)
import numpy
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# very sparse path, non-monotonic

path_x = numpy.asarray((4.0, 5.638304088577984, 6.785456961280076, 5.638304088577984, 4.0),dtype=float)
path_y = numpy.asarray((0.0, 1.147152872702092, 2.7854569612800755, 4.423761049858059, 3.2766081771559668),dtype=float)


# Upsample using spline interpolation
# then downsample using griddata nearest interpolation


# defining arbitrary parameter to parameterize the curve
path_t = numpy.linspace(0,1,path_x.size)

# this is the position vector with
# x coord (1st row) given by path_x, and
# y coord (2nd row) given by path_y
r = numpy.vstack((path_x.reshape((1,path_x.size)),path_y.reshape((1,path_y.size))))

# creating the spline object
spline = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(path_t,r,kind='cubic')

# defining values of the arbitrary parameter over which
# you want to interpolate x and y
# it MUST be within 0 and 1, since you defined
# the spline between path_t=0 and path_t=1
t = numpy.linspace(numpy.min(path_t),numpy.max(path_t),1000)

# interpolating along t
# r[0,:] -> interpolated x coordinates
# r[1,:] -> interpolated y coordinates
rr = spline(t)
xi = rr[0,:]
yi = rr[1,:]

plt.plot(path_x,path_y,'ro')
plt.plot(xi,yi,'-')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

# xii = resample(xi,20) # resample at 20 points along x
# yii = scipy.interpolate.griddata(xi,yi,path_x,method='nearest')
rbfi = Rbf(t, xi, yi, function='linear')
yii = rbfi(path_t, path_x)
# plt.plot(path_x,path_y,'or')
# plt.plot(xi,yi,'x-k')
plt.plot(path_x, yii, 'gs')

plt.show()


